Vimeo API does not return progressive video links
I use the API https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id} but it is not returning progressive video links, I am the owner of the video and I'm using a token in the request
Thanks in advance

Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue and I've already tried with all scopes enabled...
